# How to get a bullet point Black round circle instead of html code using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, ecrion

I have a simple xslt that transforms an xml to an xsl-fo but when my xml is generated it produces bullet points in

```
&#149;
```

when I use my transformation to transform to xsl-fo and pass that to ecrion to render a pdf it does not recognise the html code for bullet point I would like to add some condition to my XSLT to change that to a full black circle bullet point any suggestion please

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/doc">
<Generic><xsl:apply-templates /></Generic>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="&#149;">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="•" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: How xslt allow this template ? `<xsl:template match="&#149;">` illegal QName.. you can use char-map.

Comment: Which version of XSLT you are using?

Comment: can you show your XML and XSLT code? How about a minimal example of those? That is for us to see where &#149; comes from.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen   the system used to generate the xml does that under the hood I do not have control over that so all I use is the above XSLT and later the XSLT to produce XSL-FO I am using version 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your XML input and the expected output, we can only guess. Try perhaps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <Generic>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Generic>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#149;', '&#8226;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will replace all occurrences of the MESSAGE WAITING control character (•) with the BULLET character (•).

Answer (score 0):

Your source is in 'Windows-1252' encoding (or a similar Windows 'code page').  See, e.g., https://superuser.com/questions/1164809/whats-is-the-different-beween-western-european-windows-1252-and-ansi-encoding#1164814 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 to which it refers.

You would not need the `text()` template and the `translate()` if you could do one of these things:

- Generate your XML in UTF-8 (or UTF-16) instead of in Windows-1252
- Generate or modify the XML declaration at the start of your document so that it identifies the encoding as Windows-1252 (and use an XML processor that understands Windows-1252)
- Use an XSLT processor, such as `xsltproc`, that lets you specify the encoding of the input document
- Convert your Windows-1252 XML into UTF-8 using `iconv` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) or similar (and, post-conversion, delete or modify the XML declaration if it does, in fact, identify the encoding as Windows-1252)

Comment: I solved this by  specifying the encoding on the resulting xml to Windows-1252